# Unable to create proper sine wave with 555 timer

Tags: capacitor, oscillator, low-pass

I was trying to create a sine wave with [this circuit](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Sine-wave-generator-circuit-with-a-555-timer.php) but with different values.

[image]

When I just measure the 555 timer, I get a more or less proper square wave:

[image]

But the moment I add my LC low pass this happens:

- Green = 555 Output
- Yellow = LC Output
  [image]

Is the lowpass too much of a load for the 555 timer or what else could cause this?

What can I do to fix this?

When I connected a proper triangular wave from a generator the sine from my LC low pass was fine.

The simulation with my values:

[image]

Another thing I am wondering, the yellow line is the output of the LC.

Why does it have a flat maximum? shouldn't it slow down its slope reaching its maximum?

[image]

Ok I changed the values to: 2.2mH for the inductor and 2.2muF for the capacitor getting a resonant frequency of 2287Hz. I measured the generator with a frequency of 2300Khz. It's looking still better but still has this weird flat maximum. Interestingly I can actually hear a high-frequency noise from this circuit now:

[image]

Comment: how exactly did you change the values of the lowpass and what kind of load are you driving? Because the 555 timer strongly depends on the proper feedback signal to function correctly.

Comment: @ChristianB. Sorry forgot to add my simulation

Comment: It would be handy if you would note which waveform correspond to which node. I assume yellow is alway the node between the L and C designated "output" in this circuit and that green is ... the output of the 555? What is the last picture about?

Comment: I am sorry. Yeah. Green = 555 OUTPUT , Yellow = LC Output.

Comment: okay here is a riddle for you: a) what happens if you try to drive an LC resonance tank with a frequency strongly diverting from its resonance frequency? b) why does the 555 timer oscillate without the LC tank as well? Which components define the switching frequency? P.S. actually the answer is there at the end of the tutorial you linked.

Comment: Maybe I should just give it up and do something else. It's literally giving me a headache

Comment: What is strange is that the driver output dips 200µs before once sees a change at the filtered output. Can you confirm it is not a clipping due to your scope?

Comment: @ChristianB. I just realised that the Probe has an input range of +-1V for the Divider set to 1. *facepalm*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So what lesson did I learn? Not only the circuit can cause the problem but your measurement equipment. I didn't realize that On the x1 Setting of my probe the input range was +-1V which caused the sine wave to clip, which I referred to as "weird maximum". When I changed it to x10 it now has an input range from -10 to 10 V displaying the sine wave properly. Fun thingy, the circuit was actually producing a hearable sine noise.
[image]

Comment: If you have solved this problem, don't forget to accept your own answer, so the system can mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 1):

To cite from the link you have given yourself:

> Obviously, there are modifications you can do to this circuit. You can change the frequency of the output signal by changing the values of the RC network. If you increase the values of the RC network, this decreases the frequency. Likewise, if you decrease the values of the RC network, you increase the frequency.
>
> To create a 6Hz signal, R1= 10MΩ and C= 10nF.
>
> To create a 600Hz signal, R1= 100KΩ and C= 10nF.
>
> To create a 134Hz signal, R1= 470KΩ and C= 10nF.
>
> To create a 1.7KHz signal, R1= 33KΩ and C= 10nF.
>
> To create a 43KHz signal, R1= 1KΩ and C= 10nF.
>
> To create a 180KHz signal, R1= 150Ω and C= 10nF.
>
> To create a 252KHz signal, R1= 100Ω and C= 10nF.
>
> But remember if you modify the frequency of the square wave signal, you have to change the values of the LC network, so that resonance can be achieved for that frequency.

So the answer is: you need to modify the feedback part as well.