555 timer sinewave generation
I was trying to build a sinewave generator with NE555 IC, using these schematics I found at: Learning about Electronics - How to Build a Sine Wave Generator with a 555 Timer Chip

But the output seen on my scope is nowhere near a sinewave:

CH2: After inductor
CH3: Vin
CH4: Before inductor
I have little knowledge of designing schematics, so I have little idea of what could be going on there. While searching around about that IC, I understood that even if I would smoothen out the output, it still would be above 0V. For a proper -5V <> +5V wave I would need two 555's, or two capacitors for each wave above and below of 0V.
Please help me to understand why the output is the way it is? I also see spikes on Vin, which corresponds with output to inductor. Is that some reverse current or oscillation? Do I have to worry about it and set some diode there?
EDIT:
Okay so it was me being careless, forgot the 1uF after the inductor, now I've got the sine wave on the output, but the output frequency still doesn't make much sense.
The R1 is 2.2 kΩ which is calculated for ~7.2 kHz, so I don't understand what to make of it.

With no load and no inductor the frequency is about 17.5 kHz

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/506603/unable-to-create-proper-sine-wave-with-555-timer

Yeah, seen that post, except in my case you can see peaks above the 5V, so inductor is definitely doing something there. Scope output measurement is not capped at 5V is only a target, but you can see above that.

To get a good sine wave, you need to be at the resonant frequency of the LC.
The resonant frequency is:
\$f = \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}\$
I calculate 7.34 kHz for your LC values. Your 555 frequency is 18 kHz.
Your duty cycle should be closer to 50% with that circuit. Do you have any decoupling capacitors? Add a 0.1 uF ceramic from pin 1 to pin 8.
Vary R1 until you are much closer to the resonant frequency.
The LC will work if you are at the resonant frequency, see my answer here: RLC resonator to produce beautiful sine wave
But realize that it will only work at the resonant frequency, this is not a good general-purpose method to convert square waves to sine waves.

Thanks for the answer! I have rechecked my PCB and found missing component that i forgot, i have edited my question.


The R1 is 2.2 kΩ which is calculated for ~7.2 kHz

The difference between 7.2kHz and 6.9kHz is negligible - it's all down to component tolerances.

So i shouldn't look at frequency with no inductor basically? Dangling output will not provide proper frequency i suppose?

The dangling output is, as I understand it, within 300Hz of the desired frequency. Is that a problem?
